# Understanding the export command: Becomes the variable in already started child processes?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I still struggle with understanding the export command.

I know that it is for making variables, which are defined in a console or script, available to child processes of the console / script.

But what I'm not sure about is:

Will the variable be available only in child processes which are started **after** the export command has been executed?

Or will be variable become available **in already started** child processes too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the variable be available only in child processes which are
>   started after the export command has been executed?

Yes.

> will be variable become available in already started child processes
>   too?

No.

---

`bash` or any other shell reads statements line by line and executes them as it moves further, so any `export`-ed variable would be available only to the statements (child processes if that matters) that come after the `export`.

Comment: Makes sense according what I know so far. The bash is an interpreter which processes every command / code line it gets provided. It compiles the line, sends it to the CPU for execution and then done. Means: The child process will be started and then it lives in it's own environment. Thanks a lot.